# How to solve “undefined reference to function” error in my project?

Tags: c++

I want to `https://github.com/Rventric/Text-Detection` but if i run this command :

```
g++ -o  DEMO Demo.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

i get this error :

```
/tmp/ccTKjiBu.o: In function `main':
Demo.cpp:(.text+0x159): undefined reference to `TextDetection::detectText(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, bool)'
/tmp/ccTKjiBu.o: In function `LinkCandidate::LinkCandidate()':
Demo.cpp:(.text._ZN13LinkCandidateC2Ev[_ZN13LinkCandidateC5Ev]+0x4c): undefined reference to `Iqueue::Iqueue()'
/tmp/ccTKjiBu.o: In function `GetCandidate::GetCandidate()':
Demo.cpp:(.text._ZN12GetCandidateC2Ev[_ZN12GetCandidateC5Ev]+0x77): undefined reference to `Swt::Swt()'
/tmp/ccTKjiBu.o: In function `VericaficationTextLine::VericaficationTextLine()':
Demo.cpp:(.text._ZN22VericaficationTextLineC2Ev[_ZN22VericaficationTextLineC5Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `FilterBox::FilterBox()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

who to resolved this error ?

Comment: Fix the problem by defining the functions that the linker can't find. Based on your g++ command line, you forgot the argument to `-o` which means your `TextDetection.cpp` file wasn't being compiled -- and might have been clobbered.

Comment: @cdhowie How to do it?
give me the command please

Answer (score 3):

Whoops, you are trying to create an executable file called `TextDirection.cpp`.  You didn't specify an output file name to go with the `-o` flag.  If you want to create the executable called `demo`, then you need

```
g++ -o demo TextDetection.cpp Demo.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

Also, you might need to recover the original source file `TextDirection.cpp`, as you may have inadvertently destroyed it.

Comment: the same problem , and i changed the command To : g++ -o   Demo.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

Comment: And did you check that `TextDirection.cpp` still contains the code you expect it to contain?